# Top tabs are not visible in worldbuilding stackexchange site

Tags: bug, design

Top tab fonts are not visible in my google chrome (version Version 51.0.2704.103),
Please find the screen shot :
[image]

**Edit 1 :**

Yes , still its the same way .

I have inspected fonts :

[image]

OS : Windows 7 ultimate

Already installed and uninstalled Google chrome

[image]

Comment: Huh, that's weird.  Do you use any extensions?  If so, to help isolate the problem, could you turn them off temporarily and let us know if you still see this?

Comment: Are you still seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, that's weird. 
I'm on Version 51.0.2704.103 m (64-bit) and they look fine:

[image]

As a comparison, here's IE:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

All basically the same.

What OS are you on?
If you right click on the tab and choose "Inspect", what do you see by the font styles in the Computed tab?

[image]

I have font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;

Comment: hi andy , edited questions with some info